# iText "Coordinate outside allowed range" exception using LocationTextLocationStrategy

Tags: java, exception, itext, itext7

An exception "Coordinate outside allowed range" is thrown when I try to use `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`.

```
for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNum++)
{
    PdfPage page = document.getPage(pageNum);
    sb.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy()));
}
```

More information about the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range

    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.rangeTest(ClipperBase.java:76)
```

I have 2 similar PDFs generated by the same software, in the first the exception is thrown, in the second not.

[PDF 1 (exception)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4X8HTrR1Ssh7XtiTbARnI_-3s5FalrX/view?usp=sharing)

[PDF 2 (ok)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S1KFaEijsSLQe7RyZDfq_fegfUtploST/view?usp=sharing)

What is throwing this exception in the first PDF? How do I solve this without using the SimpleTextExtractionStrategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(According to your stack trace you are using an iText 7.* version. I updated your question tags accordingly and reproduced the issue with the current iText 7.1.2-SNAPSHOT.)*

### What is throwing this exception in the first PDF?

#### In short

Both your PDFs contain extreme **y** coordinates (beyond ISO 32000-1 implementation limits) for defining clip paths, your PDF 1 merely is twice as extreme as PDF 2 and iText clip path routines start hickup'ing somewhere in between.

#### In detail

The page content stream of page 1 of PDF 1 essentially looks like this:

```
q
[...]
% modifyCTM
0.802969 0 0 -0.802969 0 842 cm
[...]
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
q
0 0 741 98417 re W n
[...]
Q
Q
```

Thus, even considering the initial modification of the CTM you six times define clip path rectangles with a height of `98417 * 0.802969` default user units which equal approximately `79026` default user units.

ISO 32000-1 Annex C.2 *Architectural limits* on the other hand indicates

> conforming readers should accommodate PDF files that obey the constraints.
>
> [...]
>
> - The minimum page size should be 3 by 3 units in default user space; the maximum should be 14,400 by 14,400 units.

Thus, your clip path rectangle is more than five times as high as a page can be that a conforming reader is expected to support. Consequentially a conforming reader need not support your extreme clip paths.

PDF 2 is built similarly, the clip paths in question merely are `41879 * 0.802969` units high, i.e. about `33628` units, which merely is more than twice as high as needs to be supported. For some reasons iText appears to support this still.

### How do I solve this without using the SimpleTextExtractionStrategy?

You can tweak iText 7 by changing the constant `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBridge.floatMultiplier`

```
/**
 * Since the clipper library uses integer coordinates, we should convert
 * our floating point numbers into fixed point numbers by multiplying by
 * this coefficient. Vary it to adjust the preciseness of the calculations.
 */
public static double floatMultiplier = Math.pow(10, 14);
```

You can try e.g. `Math.pow(10, 10)` which works for me with both your files.

---

That been said, ISO 32000-2 appears to have dropped this specific page size limit, there merely are more generic limits plus statements like *a particular PDF processor running on a particular device and in a particular operating environment will always have practical limits.*

Thus, @iText should consider whether the current limits are such *practical limits* or should be relaxed.