# iText7(PDFSweep) throw IllegalStateException Error when redact a PDF

Tags: itext

when I use pdfAutoSweep.cleanUp(pdf) for a specific PDF, I got this Exception:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinate outside allowed range at   
 com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.rangeTest(ClipperBase.java:76)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.rangeTest(ClipperBase.java:78)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.addPath(ClipperBase.java:149)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperBase.addPaths(ClipperBase.java:321)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.clipper.ClipperOffset.execute(ClipperOffset.java:404)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpFilter.filterStrokePath(PdfCleanUpFilter.java:454)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpFilter.filterStrokePath(PdfCleanUpFilter.java:223)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.writePath(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:763)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.filterContent(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:481)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:402)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:281)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.processContent(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:377)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:302)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.processPageContent(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:186)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpTool.cleanUpPage(PdfCleanUpTool.java:304)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpTool.cleanUp(PdfCleanUpTool.java:275)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.autosweep.PdfAutoSweep.cleanUp(PdfAutoSweep.java:190)
at com.q1d.insider.redaction.PDFRedactor.removeContent(PDFRedactor.java:98)
at com.q1d.insider.redaction.PDFRedactor.main(PDFRedactor.java:250)
```

you can download the PDF use this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=106xgE0CcGjGqEovPauUfHF-eyO0XJIYL

Comment: version use is :  iText 7.1.4-SNAPSHOT and PDFSweep 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49800065/1729265 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606538/1729265

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is caused because of a constant in `pdfSweep`.
Whenever `pdfSweep` needs to redact something, it may need to modify underlying content (e.g. line drawing operations, tables, images, etc)

As you can imagine, a lot of geometry is involved. Internally, iText prefers to work with integer numbers for coordinates. However PDF documents work with floating point numbers.

Or, to quote the API

> When a document with line arts is being cleaned up, there are lot of
>   calculations with floating point numbers. All of them are translated
>   into fixed point numbers by multiplying by this coefficient. Vary it
>   to adjust the preciseness of the calculations.

There is a specific constant in pdfSweep that handles the conversion. The default value of this constant may sometimes lead to an `infinite` float value halfway through the calculations.

The way to solve it is to change the constant.

The constant is `floatMultiplier` in `pdfCleanupTool`

Comment: Thanks Joris,  Can I set the floatMultiplier in the code or have to modify  the PdfCleanupTool source code?

Comment: There is no (easy) way to set it using code.
Unless you are willing to do introspection.
But I suggest you simply modify the source code.